# how can i make token with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two entries and want to hash their values ​​and when they are clicked on another entry that is disable they will be inside this entry i show this code in jquery field i mean i want these inputs values make hash and then set to disable input

```js
$('#token').click(function() {
   if (empty($('#username').val()) && empty($('#personalid').val())) {
     $("input[name='token']").focus(function () {
         $(this).next('span').css('display','inline').fadeout(1500)
     });

   } else if($('#username').val() && $('#personalid').val()) {
       $('#token').change(function() {
          var hashToken = md5($('#username').val(),$('#personalid').val());

           $(this).val(hashToken);
       });
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="text" name="personalid" id="personalid">

<input type="text" name="token" id="token" disabled>

</form>
```

Comment: Add your ```HTML```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, probably your Jquery is undefined.